# Override php_value per virtualhost

Tags: php, apache, overriding, virtualhost

I'd like to set a distinct `upload_max_filesize` for my virtualhosts. I have some web applications in each virtualhost, so changing the value globally in php.ini is not an option, as I'd like every virtualhost to have it's own value.

So I've tried the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.test.com
 ServerAlias test.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/
 ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/test/error.log
 CustomLog /var/log/httpd/test/requests.log combined

 <Directory /var/www/html/test/>
  AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
 php_value upload_max_filesize 5M
</VirtualHost>
Alias /test /var/www/html/test/
```

In other words, I'm trying to set the value within the virtualhost .conf with `php_value upload_max_filesize 5M`. I read I'd to set an specific value for `AllowOverride` and I'm trying to set it here too, but this code doesn't work.

I'd like to keep this settings under each virtualhost section, I won't prefer using an .htaccess file.

Answer (score 8):

I would put the PHP settings in the `Directory` Directive. You should be running this as an Apache module too.

Make sure you have mod_php installed and this is uncommented in the Apache config.

```
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
```

Then you should be able to use something like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.test.com
 ServerAlias test.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/
 ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/test/error.log
 CustomLog /var/log/httpd/test/requests.log combined

 <Directory /var/www/html/test/>
  AllowOverride None
  <IfModule mod_php5.c>
     php_value upload_max_filesize 5M
  </IfModule>
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
Alias /test /var/www/html/test/
```

Make sure to reload/restart Apache after config changes. Also noticed I set `AllowOverride` to `None`. You said you  do not want to use .htaccess so you need to disable using .htaccess files. If you set it to All, Apache scans the webserver for .htaccess files everytime  it gets a request. So even if you aren't using any, it's still looking for them. So to eliminate the small performance hit, turn off htaccess files which is done with `None`.

Comment: Yup I'm using PHP as a module, I forgot to mention it. I wasn't very sure about the `AllowOverride` config, thanks for the explanation. I changed my configuration as you suggested, it seems to be right, however the change it's not being reflected

Comment: Basically I have an upload file section in the web application linked to the desired virtualhost, and I can see the change when I modify the `upload_max_filesize` directive in `php.ini`, so I have no doubt this configuration is the one I need to change. With your suggestion the application is still using the `upload_max_filesize` value stored in `php.ini` and not the one in the virtualhost, even after restarting apache: with `#apachectl restart`. What could be wrong? THANKS FOR YOUR HELP =)

Comment: Where is the php.ini file located?

Comment: At `/etc/php.ini`, phpinfo reflects this file as the one it's using. My virtualhost `.conf`file is at `/etc/httpd/sites-available/test.conf` and I know it works too for the other configurations (ex the alias) Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Hmm, try using `php_admin_value` instead of `php_value` restart apache and then check phpinfo.

Comment: I had already tried with my config. Now I try with yours and still nothing... What could it be? =( Everything seems right. I haven't changed the default configuration in `httpd.conf` about `AllowOverride` or directoryes directives.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as @Metafaniel. This answer and the numerous tutorials I found in my searching say to do just this. In my dev environment, UniServerZ 12.3.0 (a wamp), this issue persists. On my Ubuntu VPS (the live environment) with lamp this solution works just fine.

Comment: This should work outside of the `<Directory>` element as well, as you had it originally. Perhaps you have to use `php_admin_value` instead of `php_value`, if the setting is marked as `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` in the documentation. Or perhaps you have the wrong `php.ini`. You can check in the `phpinfo()` which ones are loaded. Your virtual host may have a specific path for its configuration file, and an SSL/TLS version often has another (separate) file. Or you need `<IfModule mod_php7.c>` instead of `<IfModule mod_php5.c>`.